# Intellij - adding another SpringBoot project

Tags: spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, microservices

I have generated two Spring Initializer Maven projects. I open the first one with **File-Open-location_of_the_file**, It opens up the project, when I want to open the second project it closes the previous project. I want to be able to see both projects in the project window.

I don't want the program to open a second IntelliJ window, I just want them to be inside the same window, same file explorer inside IntelliJ.
I have both projects in the /documents/microservices  folder.
I'm relatively new to IntelliJ, help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: then open the project in parent folder, but in that case you will lose the most support for `build` etc..

Comment: @Jaiwo99 how do I open in the parent folder?

Answer (score 0):

Use Import Module action: File | New | **Module from Existing Sources**.

See [Import an existing module](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#import-module) documentation for more information.

Comment: I followed these steps but unfortunately it just didn't do anything which is weird. I managed to solve the issue, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by doing this:

View -> Tool Windows -> maven -> + "Add maven projects" -> find the pom.xml from the project and then it adds it to your file explorer.